# Setting different width and height for gravatar

Tags: avatar, images, timthumb, gravatar

I've been trying to set a different width and height using the `get_avatar` function. I need to set the author's avatar in `single.php` to 60x40 size.

So let's say the gravatar looks like this:

[image]

when set to 60x40, it would look like this (resized and cropped):

[image]

However, the default `get_avatar` does not seem to allow different values for width and height, since

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $comment, '60' ); ?>
```

would simply result in 60x60-sized gravatar.

I'm not sure if this is a nice way for doing this, but I tried adding this to `functions.php`, by facilitating the TimThumb image resizer (I renamed the `timthumb.php` to `display.php`):

```
add_filter('get_avatar','change_avatar_url');
function change_avatar_url($urel) {
    $urel = str_replace("src='", "src='". bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) ."/script/display.php?src=", $urel);
    $urel = str_replace("' class", "&w=60&h=40&zc=1' class", $urel);
    return $urel;
}
```

but it (seem obviously) does not work.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As informed by @Rarst, apparently currently Gravatar only accepts one value for size. It is really unfortunate. However I managed to work-around this by facilitating `timthumb.php` and a function I found from here: [How to get gravatar url alone](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46904/how-to-get-gravatar-url-alone)

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this (it looks messy), however this works for me for creating 60x40 px size. It doesn't seem to work well when I tried with other sizes, though. Not sure why.

Well, here goes.

First I add `gravatar.com` into the list of allowed sites in `timthumb.php` (I renamed the file to `display.php`). The list is under the `$ALLOWED_SITES`.

Then in `functions.php` I put this (notice that I rename the `timthumb.php` to `display.php`):

```
// Get the gravatar URL
// source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46904/how-to-get-gravatar-url-alone
function get_gravatar_url( $email ) {
    $hash = md5( strtolower( trim ( $email ) ) );
    return 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash;
}

// Function to display the custom-sized gravatar
function custom_gravatar_timthumb($width, $height, $class) {
    $custom = get_template_directory_uri() . "/script/display.php?src=". get_gravatar_url(get_the_author_meta('email')) ."w=". $width ."&h=". $height ."&zc=1&a=c";
    echo "<img src='" . $custom . "' class='". $class ."' alt='avatar' />";
}
```

Then in `single.php` (where I display the gravatar) I put this:

```
<?php
custom_gravatar_timthumb(60, 40, "author-avatar avatar photo");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately at moment Gravatar service itself [only accepts single number for size](http://gravatar.com/site/implement/images/#size) and only serves square images.

So you have to achieve it with CSS or download, modify and cache images.

Comment: Which isn't that stupid, as gravatar requests normally slow down pretty much.

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for the answer. Managed to get a work-around but not sure if it's the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
apply_filters('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);
```

So you can filter the output:

```
function wpse69318_avatar_sizes( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt )
{
    if ( is_single() )
        return preg_replace( '/width\=\"[0-9]{1,3}\"/i', 'width="40px"', $avatar );

    // return default for other pages
    return $avatar
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'wpse69318_avatar_sizes', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget to mention that I'm trying to make the image cropped (the reason why I tried with TimThumb). With `preg_replace`, wouldn't the gravatar be resized and looked weird?

Comment: Why don't you simply specify it in CSS and then hide the stuff with `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: *Correction: "With `preg_replace`, wouldn't the gravatar only be resized without getting cropped, thus made it looks weird?" For example it would look like this: http://i.imgur.com/B5eKh.jpg Meanwhile I'm trying to make it look like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UlhBW.jpg Sorry for my bad grammar..

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it's possible to do it with CSS too... but I would also like to know if it is possible to do this by modifying the gravatar output. Can't think a good example right now, but perhaps in case of displaying certain size for author's bio?